# Remove NuGet official feed permanently

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

My network has no access to the internet

I setup a local web based feed and all is well, except that the update tab always shows me the following warning

"The remote name could not be resolved: go.microsoft.com"

This is obvious because I don't have internet connection,

If I remove the official feed from the Nuget feed sources (in the settings window)

everything works fine, until I restart Visual Studio and then the official feed comes back to the sources list.

**Is there a way to permanently remove the official feed from the list of feeds?**

I used reflector to see what is going on behind the scenes and I found out that the 
Nuget adds the official feed if it is not present when trying to persist the list of feed sources to disk.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this helps (I didn't notice this behavior before), but did you try removing the official NuGet feed entry from the 'activePackageSources' element in the NuGet.config? 
You can find it in the following directory: %UserProfile*\AppData\Roaming\NuGet

**Edit: Please make sure the nuget.config file does define at least 1 package source, or it will indeed fall back to the hardcoded official NuGet feed URL.**

Regards,
Xavier

Comment: Xavier

That is one of the first things i tried, 

whenever I restart Visual Studio and reopen the "NuGet Package Manager" the entry comes back

Thanks, Tal

Answer (score 0):

You could add a local hostfile (or DNS) entry for `go.microsoft.com` which points to a local web server, which in turn serves up an effectively empty feed file.

A bit hacky, but this trick has worked for me in the past.